# What is the meaning of tidy soul?

Tags: meaning

> It is said [10] that
>   whilst distilling nitric and sulfuric acids in his
>   kitchen, Christian Friedrich Schönbein spilt his reaction mixture and mopped it
>   up with a cotton apron... Clearly, a **tidy soul**, and doubtless not
>   wanting to vex Frau Schönbein, he washed the apron,
>   and hung it up to dry above the stove.

What does the author mean by *tidy soul*?

Comment: Is this a common usage?

Comment: Where does your difficulty lie?

Comment: It is relatively common to refer to a person as a "soul".  Of course, "tidy" just means "neat" or "clean" so it simply means that Herr Schönbein was a tidy person.

Comment: @LittleEva, I don't understand what the _tidy soul_ refers to in the text as an adjective for Mr. Friedrich Schonbein.

Comment: Did this guy invent nitroglycerin by accident?

Comment: Jason: the author is using 'soul' metaphorically. It's just meant as person, the guy is a tidy person, cleaning up after himself. That's all.

Comment: Yes, the phrase is fairly literal, it's just that the term "soul" was used instead of "person".

Answer (score 1):

The literal meaning is *a neat, orderly person*, but I am inclined to think that the meaning is more in the sense suggested in a famous quote by Mark Twain which says:

> - *Be careless in your dress if you will, but keep a tidy soul*

- Twain is telling us that it doesn’t matter what we look like on the outside. We can dress however we want, we don’t need to be concerned with our image, as long as our souls are ‘tidy.’ To keep a tidy soul is to live as a good person; to refrain from doing things which you know are wrong or evil. If you keep a tidy soul, then people will not judge you by the way you dress, but by the way you live your life.

Mr.  Christian Friedrich Schönbein is  described as a nice and correct person.

Comment: I'm thinking that the OP's example is a literal meaning of "tidy soul", like saying he was a "kind soul" or a "gentle soul", not Mark Twain's more esoteric meaning. (IMO, of course.)

Comment: @Kristina Lopez, also my thought. But I was prompting OP to be more forthcoming in order to avoid a hold.

Comment: That's what I thought at first..but a bit of research made me change my mind. I think that the meaning suggested is close to the one  explained above.

Comment: Since we're interpreting who-knows-what, you could be "righter", @Josh61. :-)

Comment: Checking Ngram it appears that the expression is not generally  used literally: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tidy+soul&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctidy%20soul%3B%2Cc0

Comment: The term is generally used as equivalent to an "individual" or "person". I would suppose its literary use would echo this.

Comment: I am referring to the expression 'tidy soul' which obviously refers to a person. What I mean is that it is not used to indicate a neat, orderly person ( literary meaning) but it is used more in the sense suggested in the quote above.

Comment: He was a "neatnik".

Comment: @Josh61 I do not think it is used in Mark Twain's sense, much as I enjoyed the extract you provided. Kristina's *gentle/loving/kind/tidy/thoughtful soul* seems to fit entirely the context.

Comment: Sorry for any misunderstanding Josh, what I meant was I was interpreting the OP's situation as referring *merely* to a human person, rather than as in the example you used.